# Как сделать меню многоуровневым?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, bootstrap, frontend

Вот моё горизонтальное меню, с выпадающим вниз пунктом `Help`. Каким образом, можно реализовать, чтобы щелкнув по `Пункту 3`, влево открывался список с новыми элементами(многоуровневое меню)?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation" data-nav-image="/views/img/blurred-image-1.jpg">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="/profile">
                          <span>
                            <i class="now-ui-icons arrows-1_minimal-left"></i>
                          </span>
                          <p>Back</p>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                       <span>
                         <i class="now-ui-icons gestures_tap-01"></i>
                       </span>
                        <p>
                          Help
                        </p>
                 </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Пункт 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Пункт 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Пункт 3</a>
               </div>
           </li>                    
       </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap какой 4 ?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 UI kit. Это элемент шаблона https://demos.creative-tim.com/now-ui-kit/index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467377/bootstrap-4-multilevel-dropdown-inside-navigation